# Using WordPress nonce cross domain

Tags: ajax, wordpress, reactjs, nonce

I'm using WordPress as a headless cms for a ReactJS app. I'm passing the `wp_nonce` as part of my rest api payload and storing it. When I include `X-WP-Nonce` in the header I get the error `Request header field X-WP-Nonce is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

The wp install lives on a subdmain. Do I need to add anything the `htaccess` file?

I added `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-wp-nonce"` to my htaccess file which clears the error but I still don't get all my pages, which using the nonce was supposed to fix.

Comment: Have you restarted your Apache server?

Comment: I'm hosted through hostgator so I don't have that option.

Comment: you should! try it locally if you can't

Comment: Shared hosting doesn't have that option

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by making a custom endpoint that spits out the data I wanted. :)